# Installing sqlite driver in Haskell using stack

Tags: sqlite, haskell

I have sqlite3 installed in Ubuntu.

```
$ which sqlite3
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/sqlite3
```

I'm trying to install the sqlite driver in Haskell and see the following error:

```
$ stack install sqlite
sqlite-0.5.5: configure
sqlite-0.5.5: build

--  While building custom Setup.hs for package sqlite-0.5.5 using:
      /tmp/stack16820/sqlite-0.5.5/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/user/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/sqlite-0.5.5.log

    [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack16820/sqlite-0.5.5/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack16820/sqlite-0.5.5/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/setup/Main.o )
    [2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/user/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /tmp/stack16820/sqlite-0.5.5/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
    Linking /tmp/stack16820/sqlite-0.5.5/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/setup/setup ...
    Configuring sqlite-0.5.5...
    Preprocessing library for sqlite-0.5.5..
    Building library for sqlite-0.5.5..
    [1 of 5] Compiling Database.SQL.Types ( Database/SQL/Types.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Database/SQL/Types.o )

    /tmp/stack16820/sqlite-0.5.5/Database/SQL/Types.hs:481:37: error:
        Ambiguous occurrence ‘<>’
        It could refer to either ‘Prelude.<>’,
                                 imported from ‘Prelude’ at Database/SQL/Types.hs:15:8-25
                                 (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
                              or ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ.<>’,
                                 imported from ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ’ at Database/SQL/Types.hs:56:1-32
        |
    481 |       FunSQLExpr f es     -> text f <> parens (commaH ppSQLExpr es)
        |                                     ^^
```

Which of ghc, stack, cabal, anaconda, sqlite should I interrogate to figure out what is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

`stack install sqlite --resolver=lts-11.22` should work

First of all i would follow [sibi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651941/sibi) advise and install the maintaned package `sqlite-simple`.

But if you want to use the deprecated one we could analyze the error:

- The error is thrown in the haskell part, the combination of `stack` and `haskell`. No mention about c code so the `sqlite` lib (or anaconda) is not involved here
- `Ambiguous occurrence ‘<>’  It could refer to either ‘Prelude.<>’, or ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ.<>’`: The simbol `<>` is defined in two modules and the client code doesn't disambiguate them (surely cause it was only in one module at the time)
- So we have to compile with a version of `Prelude` or `Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ` without the definition of `<>`

  - `Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ` is a module from the [`pretty` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty) and all versions of the package have the operator exported
  - The `Prelude` is defined in the [`base` library](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package) and it is fixed for each version of `ghc`, that in turn is fixed for each major version of the [`stackage` resolver](https://www.stackage.org/). You can set the global stack resolver in `~/stack/global-project/stack.yaml` or in each call to `stack` with the option `--resolver=`
  - The [package `sqlite`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite#Dependencies) accepts `base` versions in the range `>=3 && <5` (in fact that is the cause of the problem, it is *too* flexible)
  - If we search for `<>` in the [changelog of base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/changelog) we can see it was exported since version `4.11.0`. And that version was shipped with `ghc-8.4.1` (you can see the matrix between versions [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package#Versions)). So we have to choose a `stackage` resolver linked to a previous version of `ghc`: f.e. [`lts-11.22` with `ghc-8.2.2`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-11.22)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to install the sqlite driver in Haskell and see the following error

The `sqlite` package is deprecated in favour of [`sqlite-simple`](https://www.stackage.org/package/sqlite) So, I would recommend you to not use this. If you are looking for a much higher level of interface to sqlite, I would recommend [persistent](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) library.

If you want to still make it work, the easiest way is to just fix the compile errors by forking the code and make it work with the required GHC version.

Comment: any help for this error "Could not load module `Database.SQLite.Simple'
It is a member of the hidden package `sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0'.
You can run `:set -package sqlite-simple' to expose it " After run this command -> stack install sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0 --resolver=lts-11.22  then it returned this sqlite-simple     > Registering library for sqlite-simple-0.4.18.0..
Completed 14 action(s).